# Why can't I get the second to last result of an iterator in Python?

Tags: python, iterator, group-by

I've spent hours trying to debug this code.  I want to get the second-to-last element of a list.

```
for x, y in itertools.groupby(range(0,10), lambda x: int(x / 3)):
    print("the group's key is %d and values are %s" % (x, ','.join(map(str,y))))

temp = itertools.groupby(range(0,10), lambda x: int(x / 3))
the_last_one = None
second_to_last = None
for x,y in temp:
    second_to_last = the_last_one
    the_last_one = y
print(next(iter(second_to_last)))
```

The output of the first part, for demonstration, is:

```
the group's key is 0 and values are 0,1,2
the group's key is 1 and values are 3,4,5
the group's key is 2 and values are 6,7,8
the group's key is 3 and values are 9
```

The goal in the second part is to output the first element in the second-to-last group.  I expect `6` but instead, I get the exception `StopIteration`.  If I change the last line to:

```
print(next(the_last_one))
```

then I get the expected result of `9`.  Using a list of tuples with the same structure as the output of `groupby` works, too.  This code only fails on iterators.

Comment: Have you looked at what `groupby` is returning? It's returning four tuples of the form `(0, <itertools.grouper_object>)`. The contents of the second the grouper objects are empty except for the last one, which contains the number `9`.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are asking for. The second to last element of `range(0,10)` is simply `range(0,10)[-2]`, which equals 8

Comment: @Joel I'm not looking for the second to last result of `range`, I'm looking for the second to last result of the groupby.  The example that I gave was contrived and trivial.  The real code was working with a list of GPS coordinates, grouped by a function that converts lat/lon to x/y pixel on a mercator projection.  Try to write a function to `next` the second-to-last output of any groupby.  It'll fail.

Comment: If the list used by groupby is small, the best way to retrieve the second to last value is `list(temp)[-2]`. I'm assuming your list is very large?

Comment: You're getting the exception `StopIteration` because the second to last iterable generated by groupby is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation on `itertools.groupby`:

> The returned group is itself an iterator that shares the underlying
>   iterable with groupby(). Because the source is shared, when the
>   groupby() object is advanced, the previous group is no longer visible.
>   So, if that data is needed later, it should be stored as a list:

This means that the iterable is being consumed the first time you iterate through it.

Change

```
for x,y in temp:
    second_to_last = the_last_one
    the_last_one = y
```

To

```
for x,y in temp:
    second_to_last = the_last_one
    the_last_one = list(y)
```

to store the values as they are iterated over.

Answer (score 1):

(I think that I know what's happening but I'm new to Python.  Feel free to edit this!)

groupby is `yield`ing tuples of `(int, iterator)`.  The iterator calls the `repeat()` to get values.

When I called `next()` and advance passed the `[6,7,8]` iterator, those values disappeared from the output of `repeat()` *forever*.  `9` is the next output of `repeat()` and second_to_last is an iterator pointing into the iterator's *unsaved* past.  (Not sure about this part...)

It's not enough to save the iterator in second_to_last, I need to save the values.  The solution is to change the line to:

```
the_last_one = list(y)
```

`list()` forces the results of the iterator saved into memory.

Comment: Sounds like you have worked it out, now since second_to_last is a list you can just `print second_to_last[0]`